# Parse pandas.io.data.DataReader output

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I need some help in parsing the output from the pandas DataReader:

```
history = pandas.io.data.DataReader("YHOO", "yahoo", '2010/1/1', )
```

printing history yields:

```
Date        Open        High        Low         Close        Volume  
2010-01-04  131.179993  132.970001  130.850006  132.449997   6155300   
2010-01-05  131.679993  131.850006  130.100006  130.850006   6841400
```

but I want to save this information in SQLite like:

```
wildcards = ','.join(['?'] * len(df.columns)) 
insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s, %s)' % (tableName, symbol, wildcards)
```

How do I extract the data: `open, high, low, close, volume, adj close` from the returned reader?

I can see the structure in the debugger but do not know which/how to get the *data* into the wildcards? I would like to loop thru the data and insert each row?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframes actually have a `to_sql` method which you can use to write your data to your sqlite db without having to manually prepare your insert statements. It will create the table if it doesn't exist, or you can tell it to append to an existing table. [Check out the doco to see all the options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have used that method and it works well. I would like to have more control over the table. I would like to loop thru the dataframe to get the index (the date) and the open, high, for each entry. I can add the ticker into the table this way.I can see the data in the debugger but do not know how to reference the data in the frame. I would like to use for row in frame....

Comment: I have been searching:

So this will get the data I am after, since I am new to this! 
Is this an acceptable way to get the data out of the reader?
    count = 0
    max = history.shape[0]
    while count < max:
         print(history.index[count])
         print(history.iloc[count,0])
         print(history.iloc[count,1])
         print(history.iloc[count,2])
         print(history.iloc[count,3])
         print(history.iloc[count,4])
         print(history.iloc[count,5])
         count +=1